# Local Database Samples in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Any Samples on Local Database in windows Phone 7?i haven't work on it till now.So,
Please give some idea on that.How to save data in windows phone 7.

Answer (score 4):

There are some good examples on the internet:

- [Simple WP7.1 local databases](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Simple-WP71-Local-Database-37fcbd19)
- [WP7 Mango Local Database Support](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/06/windows-phone-7-mango-tutorial-22-local.html)

Comment: Before mango can we save localdata in  7.0  OS phones?is it support in that phones?

Comment: @Venkat - Relational data storage was added in Mango, so it's unavailable to 7.0.

Answer (score 4):

The official documentation is quite rich in this area (apologies for the link dump):

- [How to: Create a Basic Local Database Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202876%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
- [How to: Create a Local Database Application with MVVM for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286405%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
- [How to: Deploy a Reference Database with a Windows Phone Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286411%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Updating a Local Database Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394022%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

There are also good overview documentation:

- [Local Database Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
- [Local Database Best Practices for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286406%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
- [Local Database Migration Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394018%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First we have to create local database table.

```
namespace DatabaseSample.Db

{
   [Table]
   public class tblStudentDetails
   {
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string std
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
  }
 }
```

After that we can create a database context

```
   namespace DatabaseSample.Db
   {
    public class dbDataContext : DataContext
    {
    public dbDataContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }


    public Table<tblStudentDetails> studentDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<tblStudentDetails>();
        }
    }
   }
  }
```

After that we can connect to the database and can insert value to the table

```
 public class ConnectTable
{
    private const string Con_String = @"isostore:/Db.sdf";
    public ConnectTable()
    {
        using (Db.dbDataContext context = new Db.dbDataContext(Con_String))
        {

            if (!context.DatabaseExists())
            {
                // create database if it does not exist
                context.CreateDatabase();
            }
        }
    }
    #region StudentDetails
    public void AddToTableSDetails(string name,string standard)
    {
        using (Db.dbDataContext context = new Db.dbDataContext(Con_String))
        {

                Db.tblStudentDetails sd = new Db.tblStudentDetails();
                sd.name = name;
                sd.std = standard;

                context.studentDetails.InsertOnSubmit(sd);
                context.SubmitChanges();

        }
    }
    public IList<Db.tblStudentDetails> GetSDetails()
    {
        IList<Db.tblStudentDetails> sList = null;
        using (Db.dbDataContext context = new Db.dbDataContext(Con_String))
        {
            IQueryable<Db.tblStudentDetails> stQuery = from c in context.studentDetails select c;
            sList = stQuery.ToList();
        }
        return sList;
    }
 /*   public void DeleteSDetails()
    {
        using (Db.dbDataContext context = new Db.dbDataContext(Con_String))
        {
            IQueryable<Db.tblStudentDetails> stQuery = from c in context.studentDetails select c;
            foreach (var value in stQuery)
            {
                context.studentDetails.DeleteOnSubmit(value);
            }
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }*/
    #endregion
}
```